# Calling PL/SQL cursor from stored procedure to get the result

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

This is what the stored procedure looks like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TABLE.PROCEDURES IS

  type reference_cursor IS REF CURSOR;

  PROCEDURE get_attrs(output out reference_cursor) IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN output FOR
      SELECT *,
          FROM ATTRS a
         ORDER BY a.id;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE;
  END get_attrs;
END PROCEDURES;
/
```

I want to call the get_attrs stored procedure and get the output  from the output variable of type reference_cursor.

This is what I came up with but it is giving me the following error.

```
DECLARE
  outputTABLE.PROCEDURES.reference_cursor;
  output_records TABLE.ATTRS%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN TABLE.PROCEDURES.get_attrs(output);
      LOOP
        FETCH
        output INTO output_records;
        EXIT WHEN output_records%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(output_records.id);
      END LOOP;
  CLOSE output;
END;
```

And error

```
PLS-00324: cursor attribute may not be applied to non-cursor 'OUTPUT_RECORDS'
```

Any idea what I maybe doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
SET SQLBL ON;
SET DEFINE OFF;
DECLARE
output_tab ATTRS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  TABLE.PROCEDURES.get_attrs(output);
  LOOP
    FETCH output INTO output_tab;
    EXIT
  WHEN output%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(output_tab.id);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE output;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

The message is clear enough: you are trying to use a cursor-specific attribute on a non cursor element: `OUTPUT_RECORDS`.

In fact, `CURSOR_RECORDS` is not a cursor, so you need to check the `%NOTFOUND` on the cursor you are fetching, not on the variable you are fetching into:

```
EXIT WHEN output%NOTFOUND;
```